# Hide custom shipping method from checkout form in Magento

Tags: php, magento

I created custom shipping method for magento. And this method needed only for orders created programmatically from others modules.

Question: How i can to hide this method from checkout form without disabling this method in store settings?

Answer (score 1):

I assume the other modules will use your shipping method from admin context; so you ***could*** do something like this:

update your `collectRates` method like this:

```
public function collectRates(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request)
{
    if (!Mage::app()->getStore()->isAdmin())) {
        return false;
    }

    // rest of your code
```

This way, you should be able to have the shipping method active but only usable in admin context.